# Error in processing dates in FullCalendar.io script

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, icalendar

I have added the following html and script to an html page, which I have taken from another question here on StackOverflow.

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.10/index.global.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ical.js/1.4.0/ical.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/locales-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/icalendar@5.5.1/main.global.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
 
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
     initialView: "dayGridMonth",
     headerToolbar: {
       left: "prev,next today",
       center: "title",
       right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
     },
     //plugins: [DayGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin],
     events: {
       url: "x.ics",
       format: "ics",
     },
     });
 
     calendar.render();
     });
     </script>
```

The calendar renders fine but the dates do not, with this error showing in the console:

> main.global.min.js:6 Unable to process item in calendar: Error:
> invalid date-time value: "2024-02-17T::"

Does anybody have any ideas?  I do not understand the plugins if that has anything to do with this.

I was expecting or hoping dates would show up on the calendar.

Comment: Well, `2024-02-17T::` doesn't looks like a valid date to me. Does it look like a valid date to you? I'd guess your `.ics` file maybe contains some invalid data. Did you check?

Comment: P.S. Why do you have fullCalendar 5 _and_ fullCalendar 6 loaded into your page at the same time?? That makes no sense at all.